# How to connect to mail server and retrieve mails?

Tags: vb.net, email, pop3

I have mail server configuration data (server - user name - password - port) and i want to access it using vb.net and retrieve its mails in collection.
i need to parse the email body to make some operations on it.

please i need some help, i tried to search for it but i found a complex samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this library, it is very suitable for that
http://csharpmail.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

It is  possible to connect to the mail server using IMAP, check the following urls

http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/imap_readMail.asp
http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3146060/connecting-gmail-using-IMAP-in-VB-NET.aspx
http://www.aspnetimap.com/examples.aspx

more examples at http://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/imap.asp

Have a nice time

Comment: Thanks, 
I tried chilkat dll and its working with me . but there are two things 
1- its returned just the new mails not all mails in my inbox.
2- its not a free component.
what shall i do .

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try [Mail.dll email component](https://www.limilabs.com/mail):

```
Using imap As New Imap
    imap.Connect("imap.server.com")
    imap.Login("user", "password")

    imap.SelectInbox()
    Dim uidList As List(Of Long) = imap.SearchFlag(Flag.Unseen)

    For Each uid As Long In uidList
        Dim email As IMail = New MailBuilder() _
            .CreateFromEml(imap.GetMessageByUID(uid))
        Console.WriteLine(email.Subject)
    Next
    imap.Close(True)
End Using
```

Please note that this is a commercial product I developed.

You can download it here:
https://www.limilabs.com/mail